# VBA EXCEL to add empty row above a specific row [OPEN]

Tags: vba, excel, button

I am trying to write some VBA that allows a button to add an empty row, maintaining the same format, just above the row in which the SUM formula lies.

So far I achieved in creating an empty row, but I have no idea how to implement the code to let that new row inherit the *same* format style (borders and format cell included).

My code so far is:

```
    Sub InsertRev()
    Dim c As Range
    Set Rng = ActiveSheet.Range("d1:d5000")
    For dblCounter = Rng.Cells.Count To 1 Step -1
        Set c = Rng(dblCounter)
        If c.Value Like "*TOTAL*" Then
        c.EntireRow.Insert
    End If
    Next dblCounter
End Sub
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: actualy it should automatically inherit the format from the row above, did you check it ?

Comment: No it doesn't, actually it does for the format cells but not for the layout. i.e. the margin of some cells.

Answer (score 2):

You can specify arguments for the `Insert` method :

```
Sub InsertRev()
    Dim c As Range
    Set Rng = ActiveSheet.Range("d1:d5000")
    For dblCounter = Rng.Cells.Count To 1 Step -1
        Set c = Rng(dblCounter)
        If c.Value Like "*TOTAL*" Then
            c.EntireRow.Insert xlShiftDown, xlFormatFromLeftOrAbove
        End If
    Next dblCounter
End Sub
```

Comment: I had tried this method before, but it doesn't maintain the borders of the above cells. And I don't understand why...

Answer (score 1):

Can you not just copy and pastespecial the newly inserted data row, copied from the Header?...

```
TheInsertedRange.PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteFormats
```

Something like:

```
Sub InsertRev()
    Dim c As Range
    Dim Ptr As Range
    Set Rng = ActiveSheet.Range("d1:d5000")
    For dblCounter = Rng.Cells.Count To 1 Step -1
        Set c = Rng(dblCounter)
        If c.Value Like "*TOTAL*" Then
            Set Ptr = c
            Ptr.EntireRow.Insert
            c.Copy
            Ptr.Offset(-1).PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteFormats
       End If
    Next dblCounter
End Sub
```

Something like that...

Comment: I tried this code but unfortunately it doesn't let the newly generated row inherit the borders of the cells of the previous (old) row.

Comment: There isn't any inheitence going on here. You are just copying the data formats from the other data. Works for me. By the way, if you are copying 1 cell it will only use 1 cell formatting. If you copy say 3 cells using something like: c.Resize(, 4).Copy it will copy 4 cells in the new inserted range.. etc

Comment: should say If you copy say 4 cells

Comment: Ok for the data formats, that was never a problem. The problem is on the borders of the newly-generated cells, I want them to have a right border (just like the cells in the rows above) instead the cells in the new rows have **none**. That's what I'm actually looking for.

Comment: Yup I get that, but the border is a cell format. That is also copied. At leaset it is for me :)